# Find last entry of a column if another column contains a certain text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to retrieve the last entry value (number) from a column only if a certain text exists in another column within the same row.

I can retrieve the last entry no problem. But I'd like to first match "BabyFoods" in column A before getting the value. Something like the SUMIF function that checks for certain values in a column before adding things in another column.

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/(ISNUMBER(Transactions!H9:H1006)), Transactions!H9:H1006)
```

Comment: please clarify is "BabyFoods" is uniquely in Column A or is it part of a longer text string, and if so does the text string have similar structure across board? Better to provide some sample data with expected output first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the last cell in Column A that contains `BabyFoods`, and return the corresponding value from Column H, try...

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Transactions!A9:A1006="BabyFoods"),Transactions!H9:H1006)
```

To find the last cell in Column A, where the corresponding cell in Column H contains a number, try...

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((Transactions!A9:A1006="BabyFoods")*(ISNUMBER(Transactions!H9:H1006))),Transactions!H9:H1006)
```

Answer (score 1):

Small example, hopefully it's usefull for your situation:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=MAX(INDEX((A2:A10="BabyFoods")*(B2:B10="X")*ROW(A2:A10),))
```

This will return the last row with the combination of criteria "BabyFoods" in column A and "X" in column B. You could apply another `INDEX` formula, if you would want to retrieve the value of a column.